# Pseudo-differential operators - Motivation for definition of symbol

Tags: analysis, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis

I'm just beginning the study of pseudo-differential operators with focus on symbols in $S_{1,0}^m$ and I'm having a hard time grasping why we require a symbol $p(x,\xi)$ to satisfy

$$|D_{x}^{\beta}D_{\xi}^{\alpha}p(x,\xi)|\leq C_{\alpha\beta}(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{m-|\alpha|}{2}}$$

I'm sure there's a logical reason behind this and I hope someone can help me in the right path to understanding why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will very like be related to schwartz functions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, one may pseudodifferential operators for "nice" symbols, like Schwartz or compactly-supported symbols. These symbols have various limitations, and one often extends to wider ranges of classes. One such example is functions whose derivative is bounded by an *order function* (of which $\langle\xi\rangle^m$ is an example). The problem with a class like this is that they're not all invariant under a change of coordinates (i.e. preserve the symbol class). In fact, such a class is so restrictive that it leaves out differential operators. The issue that arises is that, when you pull back, you may pick up extra powers of $\xi.$

Kohn-Nirenberg symbols make it so that taking derivatives in $\xi$ improves the decay in $\xi$. These symbols *are* invariant under changing coordinates, which is an important quality when one wants to define pseudodifferential operators on manifolds.